# Why is “weak evidence” considered to make a theory more likely true than one with “no evidence” by many philosophers?

Tags: philosophy-of-science

Suppose Jack and Jill both claim to be psychics. They both decide to make 100 predictions. Jack ends up getting 14 predictions right. Jill ends up getting no predictions right.

Most would believe neither.

However, depending on which epistemologists you talk to, some would say that there is technically more evidence of Jack being a prophet than Jill, but just not enough to state that Jack is a prophet. If many would in their mind put the probability of Jack being a prophet as higher than Jill, but consider the probabilities to be minuscule for both, it seems that this is a mistake.

Having “some but not enough evidence” seems to give some illusory benefit to a theory compared to a theory with “no evidence”.

Shouldn’t having not enough evidence be treated the same as having no evidence? I feel as if this maps to reality better anyways. Because of what we know about the world, having never observed enough evidence for psychic things working out, I fail to see how getting 14 correct guesses should be classified as being any kind of evidence at all. You either have enough guesses that are way more than expected by chance or you don’t. Yet most philosophers don’t seem to treat evidence as discrete states.

Comment: Why wouldn't we have grounds for at least attributing *infinitesimal* improvements in likelihood for the thesis that Jack is a psychic? However, I'm not sure that analytic philosophers would often be motivated to believe in psychics regardless of how often their predictions came true; see the [clairvoyance problem](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/reliabilism/#ClaiProb) in reliabilist epistemology for some details.

Comment: Without citations, this comes across as a question about a straw man. Who are these epistemologists and where do they make this kind of assertion?

Comment: It is commonplace in Bayesian epistemology to treat evidence as such. See the degree of belief section here: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/epistemology-bayesian/

Comment: @KristianBerry Because the concept of infinitesimal improvements in likelihood makes no sense, especially because a theory is either true or false. If a psychic got predictions right that are way more than what chance dictates, we would simply believe in he is one. Our credence would be that he is one. If he does not, we simply don’t have enough evidence. As such, it should be dismissed given the priors favoring no psychics

Comment: @temptrt, it might make no sense to you, and infinitesimals often supposedly make no sense to all manner of analysts, but theories might not be either true or false; bivalence is not certain, neither is exclusive disjunction more generally, and so many of us are trained in thinking about theories more "probabilistically," which then means using at least fuzzy real numbers if not outright infinitesimals (it seems easy to me to use surreal infinitesimals but other examples of nonstandard analysis trespass upon exclusive disjunction/bivalence, which in the end I *do* accept, though).

Comment: At any rate, I am wary of saying, "*X* doesn't make any sense," or, "*X* is meaningless," just like that. I am more inclined to say, "*X* doesn't make sense *to me*, *for now*," while I am also more inclined to suppose that other people who talk about *X* do, ultimately, have something meaningful (to them!) in mind.

Comment: @KristianBerry I mean, the idea of that can be somewhat tested. Just imagine the scenario I outlined in front of you. Adam makes 14 guesses out of 100. John makes 0 out of 100. Is there any scenario in which you think you can possibly make any money betting on Adam being a prophet? If not, in what sense is Adam more likely to be a prophet than John?

Comment: There are a wide range of definitions/theories of probability, and I'm not well-versed in any of them. Just the same, then, I would no more claim that people who *are* well-versed in those theories will somehow turn out to have just been speaking gibberish all along, than I would claim that I have grounds for avoiding vaccines until I somehow manage to run experiments on them personally.

Comment: Simply because most people's experience is in a narrow and small (static) universe and thus they never saw any Boltzmann brain or anything the like. Indeed if the universe is eternally expanding faster and faster which is the most likely scenario according to contemporary cosmology then Boltzmann brains would most likely much more than supposed evolved stable human minds on a tiny mediocre earth!...

Comment: It’s actually the opposite. With zero correct answers I would think that Jill is a psychic who always lies.

Answer (score 1):

Your question assumes that many philosophers would rate Jack as being more likely to be a psychic than Jill- where is the evidence for that?

Whether some evidence is more suggestive than none depends on the context and is a matter of degree.

To use your thought experiment- suppose it were possible to define a number, N, of correct predictions that suggested the existence of psychic abilities. Suppose Jill makes no valid predictions and Jack makes N-1- would you consider Jack's performance to be no different to Jill's?

Comment: Yes I would consider them to be the same assuming that that threshold actually exists. In reality, it is hard to to come up with one but the point remains. Subjectively, atleast, you either have enough evidence or you don’t. There’s no such thing as increasing likelihood. You either believe or you don’t. The rational position when you don’t have enough evidence should be to go with the priors, in this case, not believing he was psychic. Lastly, Bayesian epistemologists would consider one of these theories as more likely than another. Google the degree of belief concept

Comment: Then you would be wrong. Suppose you had two experimental set-ups to detect some phenomenon. One did not detect it at all but the other almost, but not quite, made enough detections to be statistically significant. Would you treat both set-ups as having failed, or would you consider one of them to be a more promising candidate for further development?

Comment: You just smuggled in a change in your scenario. If you are simply detecting something, then any sort of detection by definition is not enough evidence. If it is possible to falsely detect something, then yes, I would say that if you don’t have enough evidence, and our prior knowledge suggests that it DOESN’T exist, then yes, you should not give it weight. 

Keep in mind that statistical significance comes from an arbitrary threshold us humans made up

Answer (score 0):

The core of the philosophic mindset is to learn to question one's assumptions, the walls of the boxes we think within.  This is often difficult for us, and asking others to help can be very beneficial in this process.  Your question includes many such opportunities.

A major assumption you make is that of realism - that there is a "world out there".  Another is that theories about it can be either TRUE or FALSE, because you think there is One True Logic, and that is classical two mode logic.

Realism is not necessary for empiricism.  Most scientists are realists, but philosophers realize that empiricism, science, and our overall interaction with the world, can operate off a variety of alternate assumptions.  The most common alternative used is nominalism.  I am a realist, but am so by deliberate choice, not  because I am blind to the possibility of other ways to conceptualize empiricism.

What logic applies to our world, is NOT classical logic, as you assume.  Logicians have established that there is not One True Logic, but an infinitude of logics: https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/think/article/abs/guide-to-logical-pluralism-for-nonlogicians/EDFDFA1C9EB65DB71848DABD6B12D877  This produces LOTS of problems for logicians, as this paper illustrates:  http://www.mbph.de/Logic/Pluralism.pdf  As that paper notes, classical logic is considered to have enough faults when applied to the world, that only exotic paraconsistent logics are entertained as possible nominees for One True Logic, and in practice logicians just use different logics in different cases.

In empiricism, and reasoning about our world, we DON'T use classical logic and its True/False dichotomy.  Instead we use a four state logic:  a) not enough justification to treat a premise as other than uncertain, b) a premise is poorly enough constructed that it is unevaluable, c) there is sufficient justification to treat the premise as a useful working hypothesis, d) there is enough contrary evidence to treat the premise as dismissed.  Your presumption that we should do reasoning, and empiricism, using two state logic has been rejected long ago, as ineffective/unworkable.

You also presume that there are objective criteria for establishing truth.  This is false -- all empiricism, and basically all reasoning as well, relies upon judgement.    The criteria for establishing "there is sufficient justification" is a judgment call.  Note those who advocate for Bayesian statistics do not get out of this -- Bayesian statistics bury the judgment in the assumed prior, and in the evidence weighting -- there is no evading use of judgement in empiricism and reasoning.  And Bayesian statistics is MORE susceptible to confirmation bias than frequentist statistics, by allowing the bias to be assumed and hidden, embedding the bias in ways that are easy to rationalize/deny.

So -- let us go back to your psi "experiment".  You falsely assert that a psychic should get 100% true predictions, and if that is not the case, then a psychic capability does not exist.  This is very poor reasoning.  Most real phenomena in our world, are far less than 100% in their predictive success.  For instance, we have an economy, and we have a science that studies that economy, Economics.  Yet the predictions of economists are FAR less than 100% accurate! Economies are complex, and the things that economists have established that matter to them -- markets, money supply, business cycles, etc. -- are only part of the actual behavior of our world.  Predictions based on them -- are often wrong.  yet this is VERY useful information, and the generalities of economic theory give us useful insights that help us to better understand our economy, and improve how we manage it.  Predictions can be far less than 100% and still reflect a real effect/phenomenon.

Apply this to psychics.  A psychic claims to have info about the future, but we know that human psychology involves a LOT of nose/variables/etc, and we can even be regularly confused about that we think and why.  A psychic, if they DO have access to knowledge of the future, could therefore reasonably be assumed to sometimes be mistaken in that knowledge, and misidentify real perceptions as passing flights of imagination, and vice versa.  Therefore, testing for prediction accuracy should be done statistically, and with non-psychics as a control.

Lets take your proposed 0% and 14% predictive accuracy and flesh out the experiment a bit.  The control is critical here.  IF the control sample shows 0% predictive accuracy too, with a small standard deviation, and the 14% for the better psychic is repeatable, then it would be entirely reasonable to think the better psychic has psychic powers.  AND STILL generally not act on those predictions, because of their inaccuracy.  IF the control has an average prediction rate of, say 7%, with a =/-10% sigma, then neither psychic should be considered to be psychic at all.  But if the control has a 7% prediction rate, with say a 2% sigma, then the 14% psychic is HIGHLY INTERESTING, as is the 0% psychic.  Parapsychologists have found a strong "sheep and goats" effect in controlled studies, where committed skeptics sabotage their parapsychic insights, and deliberately suppress any psychic knowledge they might have.  If psychic 2 turned out to be a skeptic whose true views were being masked as part of the experimental setup, then both results would actually support the psychic hypothesis.

Note, contrary to your presumption, the parapsychology community has confirmed multiple psi phenomenon to the standards of science:  https://parapsych.org/articles/36/55/what_is_the_stateoftheevidence.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Your example turns on whether they regard the true predictions as weak evidence, as opposed to considering them to be more likely to be random chance or based on non-psychic phenomena.  Indeed, depending on the predictions made, Jill might appear more likely; if they were flipping a coin and Jill got every single one wrong, that's more improbable than getting fourteen right.

A case where there actually is weak evidence:  a crime lab tests a drink for a poison.  It comes back negative.  This is weak evidence that the drink was not poisoned, since various poisons need various tests.  But it's certainly better than not having any test for any poison.